# jquery select anything but this and its descendents

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figured out how to make a menu disappear when the user clicks outside of it.
my approach is this :

```
$(*).not(menu).bind('click', function() { $(menu).hide() })
```

for some reason this is not working. any idea what I might be doing wrong? 
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this

```
$('*').
```

is evil, mad and bad karma!

use instead

```
$(document.body).bind('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.id !== 'yourmenuid' || $(e.target).parents().is('#yourmenuid'))
       $('#menuid').hide();
});
```

Try to avoid the universal selector `*` at all times. Sizzle will indeed query all available elements in your markup which is terribly expensive.

Comment: And shouldn't the condition be `if (target is NOT within menu)` ... as opposed to `if (target is within menu)` as you have here.

Answer (score 3):

Quickest and easiest way to do this:

```
jQuery(document).delegate(':not(#menu-id)', 'click', function(){
    $('#menu-id').hide();
});
```

Alternatively:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if ( e.target !== menu && !$.contains(e.target, menu) ) {
        $(menu).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea.

Writing `$('*')` will add your click handler to *every single element in the document*, which will be slow.  In addition, it won't handle clicks on any new elements added later.  (Unless they bubble up)

Instead, you should handle the `click` event for the root element, like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target === menu || $(e.target).parents().is(menu))
        return;
    $(menu).hide();
});
```

All `click` events on any element will eventually bubble up to the root element (unless you cancel it), so this will handle every single click.

Comment: `parents` is a method -- not a collection or jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, have you considered [`jQuery.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)?

```
$('#menu > ul > li').hover(
    function() { $('ul', this).show(); }, 
    function() { $('ul', this).hide(); }
);
```

Appearing/disappearing on mouseover/mouseout is a more common practice. You could even make it more smooth using [`jQuery.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and [`jQuery.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

```
$('#menu > ul > li').hover(
    function() { $('ul', this).slideDown(250); }, 
    function() { $('ul', this).slideUp(100); }
);
```